# Virtual PC 2007 is not working with Windows 7 64-bit and Windows mobile

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-mobile

I'm trying to get a connection to the internet with my Windows Mobile 6 device emulator but it won't connect.

I get this message every time I try to setup a network in the emulator:

> #### Device Emulator
>
> The required Virtual Machine Network Driver could not be found. Make sure that Virtual PC 2007 is installed. You can install Virtual PC 2007 from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=46859

[image: device emulator dialog]

But I do have it installed. However, I get the following warning so I'm not sure if this is why it does not work:

> #### Caution - Virtual PC
>
> Virtual PC could not open the Virtual Machine Network Services driver.
>
> Access to the external network and host will be unavailable to all virtual machines using virtual networking. Virtual machines using virtual networking will still be able to access other virtual machines using virtual networking.
>
> To fix this this problem, re-enable the Virtual Machine Network Services driver on one more more ethernet adapters or reinstall Vitrual PC.

[image: caution dialog]

[image: screenshot of desktop with dialogs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Virtual PC Guy's Blog article [Fixing broken virtual networking](http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2007/01/15/fixing-broken-virtual-networking.aspx).

This article describes how to fix two common reasons for this problem:

- The Virtual Machine Network Services
  driver is installed but not enabled
- The Virtual Machine Network Services
  driver is installed and enabled, but
  does not seem to be working.